# Java 3D game development

Tags: java, game-engine

Hi everyone.

This year I am entering my last year in college and for my final exam I have to create a project. I am thinking of creating a 3D game in Java. I know Java SE and have plenty of resources in case I need help. My only problem is I don't have any idea for what type of game to create. At first I wanted to create a 3D chess game but a friend thought of that first and the project is already taken.

Can anyone give me some ideas on some games that are as complex in logic as a chess game and can also prove (if I am able to finish it of course) that I am a good programmer to my examiners? And also, if it exists, a link to the game itself to have an idea of what I am building.

Comment: This type of question is not suited for SO (per the FAQ). However, I would recommend doing something "novel" with 3D and/or a variation of an existing game. Three things I did where a space-shooter "on a sphere", a break-out clone with hundreds of balls and many skewed lines (not bricks), and a top-down multiplayer shooter with limited visibility based on ray casting. Playing some flash games on a site like kongregate may also lead to some good ideas.

Comment: Tangent to your question: look at jMonkey engine for developing 3D games in java.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.gamedesign.jp/flash/dice/dice.html
It's like risk but way simpler. You'd have to create an algorithm that generates the map but it'd not be too hard. I'd say you'd be well versed in Java if you can do this. Plus, it'd be a really fun game for your professor

Comment: I was hooked on this game for a while but managed to forget it and be productive again. Curse you for reminding me!

Comment: @jhocking haha, I'm still addicted to the kdice.com spinoff!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of strategy boardgames similar to chess, with simple rules that combine in complex patterns. For example, Stratego or Othello.

(Those games are more recent and may be trademarked names, but that's not an issue for a student project.)